# Stop .scroll function to fire after certain spot

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scroll

I have multiple conditional `if` statements wrapped in a `$(window).scroll` function. Each conditional `if`'s have different `$('#section').offset.top` spots on the document. But, the problem is each `if`'s statement keeps firing after a window scroll passes different sections on the page.

Below is a short example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function(){
  
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    if(wScroll > $('#section-one').offset().top){
 // do something!
        console.log('foo');
    }else{
        //stop the something!
    }
    
    if(wScroll > $('#section-two').offset().top){
 // do something!
        console.log('foo');
    }else{
        //stop the something!
    }
    
  });

});
```

The `console.log()` still would fire both `foo` & `bar` after the user scrolls past the two `offset.top` points.

How can i stop the each `console.log()` and it's elements to fire only inside its respected sections height's and not overlap other top conditional triggers. All in order to have optimal browsing performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to log when the scroll is within the element, you could do something like this:

```
    if(wScroll > $('#section-one').offset().top 
       && wScroll < ($('#section-one').offset().top + $('#section-one').height()))
    {
        console.log('foo');
    }
```

Just checks if the scroll position is between the top and bottom of the element

You can do the same for section-two